# Expanding a complex function in Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis

Expand the function
$$ f(z) = \frac {2(z + 2)} {z^2 − 4z + 3} $$
in a Taylor series about the point $ z = 2 $ and find the circle C inside of which the series converges. Find a Laurent series that converges in the region outside of C.

I tried writing the denominator as $ (z-3)(z-1) $ to find the singularities $ z = 1,3 $ both simple. There exists a circle around $ z = 2 $ such that $f(z) $ is analytic so we can write it as a Taylor series. I got stuck trying to make the function look like a known Taylor series like $e^z$ or $\frac {1} {1-z}$

Comment: Start with doing partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: Without computing the Taylor series you can tell that its radius of convergence is $1$ because $|2-3|=1$ and $|f(z)|\to \infty$ as $z\to 3,$ while  $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z-2|<1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Starting with a standard partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{2(z+2)}{z^2-4z+3}=\frac{3}{1-z}-\frac{5}{3-z}
$$
you may then set $u:=z-2$, that is $z=u+2$, obtaining
$$
\frac{3}{1-z}-\frac{5}{3-z}=-\frac{3}{1+u}-\frac{5}{1-u}
$$ with $u \to 0$ as $z \to 2$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Kind of. Here is what I have: $$ \frac {-3}{1+u} - \frac {5}{1-u} = -3 (1 – u + u^2 – u^3 + ...) - 5 ( 1 + u + u^2 + u^3 + …) $$
Both series converg when $ |u| < 1 $ therefore $ |z-2|<1 $ The series converges in the circle centered at $ z = 2 $ with a radius of 1.

Comment: Yes. Then gather the two general terms, you get the Taylor series expansion: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-3(-1)^{n}-5)(z-2)^n$

Comment: For the second part of the question. Find a Laurent series that converges in the region outside of C. C in this case is $  |z−2| < 1 $. The outer circle in this case would be the whole plane because the only singularities are $ z =1,3 $ ?

Comment: For the Laurent series, you just write $$-\frac{3}{1+u}-\frac{5}{1-u}=\frac{1}{u}\left(-\frac{3}{1+1/u}+\frac{5}{1-1/u}\right)$$ then expand 'geometrically' since in this case $\left| \frac1u \right|<1$ ($|z-2|>1$).

Comment: Thank you very much. I got $$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-3(-1)^n +5) \frac {1}{(z-2)^{n+1}} $$ converges in the outer circle where $ |z-2|>1 $. Does the sum look correct?

Comment: It is fine! @Josh

Answer (score 2):

Split them into partial fraction and upon solving you will get,

$  \frac {2(z+2)}{(z-1)(z-3)} = \frac {3} {(z-(-1))} + \frac {5} {z-3} $

taylor's series expansion is

$ \frac {1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-a} + \frac {x-a}{(1-a)^2} + \frac {(x-a)^2}{(1-a)^3} + ...$

so for $\frac {3}{(z-(-1)} $ , value of a=-1    i.e.,      $ \mathcal\ z ^\left(-1 \right) $ $\left[ \frac {1}{z-a} \right] $

the taylor's series for

$\frac {3}{z-(-1)}$ = $ 3 \{  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{(x+1)}{4} +\frac {(x+1)^2}{8} + ...\}$

similaryly for $\frac {5}{(z-3)} $ , value of a=3       i.e.,   $ \mathcal\ z ^\left(-1 \right) $ $\left[ \frac {1}{z-a} \right] $

the taylor's series for

$\frac {5}{z-3}$ = $ 5 \{  \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{(x-3)}{4} +\frac {(x-3)^2}{8} + ...\}$

Comment: I think the value of a should be 2 in both cases because the expansion is being done around the point z = 2, right?